# Question about converting a list of strings to ints

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to convert one column in my numpy array from strings to ints, however when I tried the methods I found online, it didn't mutate the column. Here is my code:

```
frequencies = np.array([['a', '24273'],
               ['b', '11416'],
               ['c', '8805'],
               ['d', '6020']])
               frequencies[:, 1] = frequencies[:, 1].astype(int)
               print(frequencies)
```

The array is unchanged when I print the output.

Comment: Perhaps the examples you saw were in `pandas`.  In `numpy`, the entire array needs to be the same type.  In `pandas`, each column can be a different type.

Comment: You can make a `structured array`, using a compound dtype, `np.dtype(['f0','U3'),('f1',int)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assert the datatype for the `frequencies` array to be `dtype=object` to accomodate for different data types; `int`s and `string`s.

```
import numpy as np 

frequencies = np.array([['a', '24273'],
               ['b', '11416'],
               ['c', '8805'],
               ['d', '6020']],dtype=object)
frequencies[:, 1] = frequencies[:, 1].astype(int)
print(frequencies)

[['a' 24273]
 ['b' 11416]
 ['c' 8805]
 ['d' 6020]]
```